# Checkbox within Rails Form: Default to checked if value not set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox

I have the following checkbox field within my rails form:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :education, "Education Employee): " %>
  <%= f.check_box :education%>
</div>
```

The checkbox defaults to not being checked.  What I want for it to do is to default to being checked UNLESS the value is already set to true/false.  If the value is already set to true/false then display the checkbox value of that set value.  In other words:  If the set value is `nil` then default to being checked.

I attempted this but it didn't work for me:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :education, "Education Employee: " %>
  <%= f.check_box :education, checked: true if f.object.education.nil? %>
</div>
```

I did not get much info from the [checkbox documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box).

Comment: Why don't you add the default `true` to your database column? Or set the default when you initialize the instance.

Comment: @spickermann I could add a database constraint, but I was wanting to see if I could keep it at the application level.

Comment: @spickermann YES! thank you!  Didn't think of initializing the default value within the instance.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer to set a default in the database. But when you want to keep this at the application level – as you wrote in a comment – then you can set defaults after initializing an instance.

```
# in your model
after_initialize :set_defaults

private
def set_defaults
  self.education = true if education.nil?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better way is to set default values in the initial migration like:

```
 def change
    add_column :model, :education, :boolean, default: true
 end
```

Or if it's an existing column:

```
def change
    change_column_default :model, :education, true
end
```

I know this is an old post but maybe it'll help someone in the future